# Solving equation involving factorial

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I have the following problem:

$$
N^n(N-n)!=A
$$

Where $N$ and $A$ are constants.  I want to solve this equation for $n$ (for a variation of the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)), but I have little experience with combinatorics.

An approximate answer is acceptable, so I've tried using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but no matter how I manipulate it, I can't get an answer to fall out.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method is going to depend quite a bit on the relative sizes of $N$ and $A$, but here's an idea that might work well in practice.

Divide both sides of the equation by $N!$ to yield
$$
\frac A{N!} = \frac{N^n(N-n)!}{N!} = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \bigg( 1 - \frac jN \bigg)^{-1}.
$$
Take logs of both sides to obtain
\begin{align*}
\log \frac A{N!} &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \log \bigg( 1 - \frac jN \bigg)^{-1} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac jN + O\bigg( \frac{j^2}{N^2} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)}{2N} + O\bigg( \frac{n^3}{N^2} \bigg).
\end{align*}
For many ranges of $N$ and $A$, this shows that $n$ will be about $\sqrt{2N\log(A/N!)}$.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, this is very useful...I'm going to ponder this for a bit.

Comment: Thanks so much, Greg.  I would like to ask you some questions about your approach and where I can learn more about some of the manipulations you used.  If you're down, could you email me at e@zepln.com?

Comment: @EthanBrown: I might be a little too busy to be a good resource for you. Maybe edit this problem to include your additional questions, or start a new problem, to take advantage of crowdsourcing?

Comment: No problem, I understand how that goes!  Thanks again for your answer.