# Equation with factorial and exponentiation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, factorial

We know $0 < a \le {1 \over 2}$ and $0 < b \le
 {1 \over 2}$. I need a good upper
bound for the smallest integer $n \gt 0$ such that:

$$\frac{a^n}{n!} \le b$$

Probably related to the [birthday problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/466117/4414),
but motivation is some numerics.

Comment: Are $a,b$ positive?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it is trivial if $a<b$, since

$$\frac{a^1}{1!}<b$$

So the real problem is $0<b<a\le\frac12$.  The simplest upper bound:

$$\frac{a^n}{n!}\le a^n\le b\implies n\le\log_a(b)$$

A stronger upper bound using Stirling:

$$\frac{a^n}{n!}\le\frac{(ae)^n}{n^n}\le\left(\frac{ae}2\right)^n\le b$$

$$n\le\log_{ae/2}(b)$$

where $e\approx2.71828$

Comment: Works also for a >= 1/2 I guess! Like for example a < 2/e.

Comment: Of course, Stirling's approximation works fine for larger $n$.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite simple inequalities
for $n!$ are
$(n/ei)^n < n!
< (n/e)^{n+1}$.

These should help.

Comment: It's pretty hard to solve for $n$ in things like $(cn)^n=b$, so you may wish to elaborate.

Comment: Possibly small typo ei -> e.

Comment: @j4nbur53 I thought the same, but that's kind of the right side of the inequality?  Maybe?  not entirely sure what's going on here.